# How to get rid of these warnings after installing zend core?

Tags: thread-safety, php-extension, php-internals

Really annoying!

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: bcmath: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: curl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gd: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imap: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mbstring: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: soap: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sockets: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysqli: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is already asked. You are trying to load non-thread-safe extensions into PHP, that was compiled with thread-safety. Recompile either PHP or modules.

Answer (score 0):

the error is saying that 
module modules have  thread-safety=0
and PHP has  thread-safety=1 and these 2 should match.

The compile option for thread safety should be identical.